# Ask LibreOffice?

Tags: discussion

I found this site when trying to find an answer for something: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/8631/upper-limit-to-number-of-rows-in-calc/

I noticed it had a very similar theme to StackExchange, complete with user profiles, identical badge names, votes system etc. etc.

I went into the SE dropdown and type `Libre` and no results were found... is this a related SE or has this site just cloned everything with LibreOffice stylings?

Comment: This appears to be a legit "clone". See, in addition to dupe, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270694/why-does-ask-libreoffice-org-look-so-much-like-so) and [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3758/why-libreoffice-is-not-using-the-stack-exchange-platform-for-qa/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard ahh I see - thanks :D

Comment: Cheers, and welcome to Meta!

Comment: @treyBake: You can [ask LibreOffice questions on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice).

Comment: @NicolBolas wouldn't this question be off-topic there?